# Ionic CameraPreview doesn't wait until properly initialized

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have a CameraPreview in an Ionic 3 app, and I am trying to set parameters to it: flash on/off, focus mode, color effect, etc. The problem is that these can only be set when the CameraPreview object is already initialized and the camera image is showing. The same goes for all methods which return parameters of the device.

Supposedly the object's methods are returning Promises, but they don't work properly. I have two different phones for testing, a Samsung J120 with Android 6.0.1 and a Motorola Moto G with 4.4.4. On the Motorola the following code works properly and the camera parameters are set after the camera is initialized. On the Samsung it fails with the error message "No camera".

So what is wrong here? The `setFlashMode` block will throw an error, because the camera isn't running yet. Don't believe the official docs, it says that `setFlashMode` takes callback parameters. It doesn't.

```
this.cameraPreview.startCamera(cameraPreviewOpts)
  .then(
      () => console.log('Camera started.'),
      (error) => console.log('Camera error: ', err)
   )

//  show camera ----------------------------------------

  .then(
      () => {
        this.cameraPreview.show()
        .then(
            () => console.log('Camera showing'),
            (error) => console.log('Error showing camera: ', err)
        )
   })

//  set flash ----------------------------------------

   .then(
       () => {
         this.cameraPreview.setFlashMode('on')
         .then(
             () => console.log('Flash mode set OK'),
             (error) => console.log('Error setting flash mode: ', error)
         )
   })
```

Comment: you can use promises like `return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {this.cameraPreview.startCamera(cameraPreviewOpts)
  .then(
      () => {console.log('Camera started.'); resolve()},
      (error) => console.log('Camera error: ', err)
   )`

Comment: Yes, that was the solution after all. Unfortunately these methods don't return a proper promise, it gets immediately triggered before the method actually finished running.

Comment: can u wrap the `startCamera` function in a promise...and then resolve it in `show camera` block? and then have the final `.then()` of the promise you wrapped the other two .then's in

Comment: Yes, that's what I did.

Comment: what about putting `this.cameraPreview.show()
        .then(
            () => console.log('Camera showing'),
            (error) => console.log('Error showing camera: ', err)
        )` inside the first `.then` if camera is started....try putting 2 block inside 1, and 3 block inside 2 block inside 1 block